# What's the meaning of "link!=None" in this if condition?

Tags: python

```
finally:
  if link!=None:
     link.close()
```

I was trying to learn how to make a flowchart using `while` and `if` conditions, and came across this one which I couldn't understand.
Could you please tell me if you know what this means.

Comment: Can you give us more context about what is ```link```?

Comment: The code within the `if` statement executes only if the `link!=None` is satisfied. You should definitely learn basics of python from a tutorial. There is a great number of them online. Stackoverflow is not a school. BTW, it is bad practise to test `link!=None`. It would be much better to test `link is not None`.

Comment: You could learn more about ```None``` here: https://realpython.com/null-in-python/

Comment: yes of course! link = open(path)   path = "studen_info.txt"   its basically a var linked to file , i guess

Answer (score 1):

`finally` is part of [The try statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) and is always executed whether the code inside the `try` hit an exception or not. You can do many things in a `finally` suite but one common use is to cleanup any temporary objects created in the try code. This one does exactly what it says, if something has been assigned to `link`, it closes it.

Answer (score 0):

You specifically asked for the meaning of `link!=None` in the if condition. This code snippet could be more readable if this would be written like:

```
if link:
    link.close()
```

Then it should be clear, if there is a link then close it. As it is written it is more complicated to understand:

```
if link != None:
    link.close()
```

This means that a link should only be closed if the value of the link is not `None`. Both variants should lead to the same result.

But why *should*? It is indeed a bit different. The second approach (as provided in the question) only closes the file if anything except `None` is assigned to the variable `link`. The first approach will close the link if anything that can be evaluated to `True` is assigned. If we can ensure that a link is either a file object (would be evaluated to `True`) or `None` (would be evaluated to `False`), I would strongly recommend writing `if link:` instead of `if link != None` (or even better as `!=`: `if link is not None`).